# Make Biblatex (Bibtex) recognize equal subsequent postnotes

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

*for **tl;dr** check the example*

I am using Biblatex (biber-backend) as bibliography tool, but I guess this question could be relevant for Bibtex as well.
The style I use is: authoryear-icomp

I cite like this:

```
\****cite[<number>]{<bibkey>}
```

That way Biblatex recognizes the number as page and a repeated citation cites as:

```
(ibid.)
```

Now to the **problem**:
I have same sources with special page numbers like "20:16" (or postnotes like "chapter XY"), so Biblatex does not recognize it as page number and I have to cite it like:

```
\****cite[p.~20:16]{<bibkey>}
```

That of course means Biblatex does not recognize repeated citation and cites it as:

```
(ibid., p. 20:16)
```

instead of:

```
(ibid.)
```

**Example** *(how it should be)*

```
<text1> \cite[\ibid{chapter XY}]{authorXY}. <text2> \cite[\ibid{chapter XY}]{authorXY}
becomes:
<text1> (authorXY, chapter XY). <text2> (ibid.)
```

*but*

```
<text1> \cite[\ibid{chapter XY}]{authorXY}. <text2> \cite[\ibid{chapter AB}]{authorXY}
becomes:
<text1> (authorXY, chapter XY). <text2> (ibid., chapter AB)
```

The **ibid{...}** - command is just a placeholder, because I don't know how to achieve, what I described. It is just to explain the idea.
I hope that clears things up.

Help and ideas are very much appreciated :)
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: A MWE would be be very much appreciated (which style do you use?). Of course you could just make `biblatex` accept `:` as page number characters (via `\DeclareNumChars*{:}`), then there would be no need for the `p.~` prefix.

Comment: thanks, this is a good idea, but doesn't exactly accomplish all I try to achieve. I want that also things like chapter are recognized.

Comment: OK, a proper MWE would still help us, especially because I always get the page number after the ibid, even if I have a bare page number. It would also help if you could include the use cases you had in mind. (More complicated constructs etc.)

Comment: Sorry, I already added it in the OP, have forgotten to mention it in the comment.

Comment: Yes, you added the style you are using, a full proper MWE is still missing though. Your edit with `\cite****[\ibid{XYZ}]{<bibkey>}` confuses me, sorry. Another thing you should think about is where you want to draw the line on what postnote is to be dropped when doubled (`p. 14`, `chapter 14` etc.) and what is to be retained, you probably would not want an important postnote comment to be dropped, just because it happens to appear twice.

Comment: added an example, hope that explains what I mean and doesn't confuse more :D I cant think of an MWE because I have no idea how to achieve what I want (the \ibid{...}) is just a placeholder for a command to let biblatex know I want it to recognize it for changing it to ibid.

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused about the `\ibid` command suddenly appearing, do you want only postnotes seasoned with this (presumably to-be-defined) command to be dropped if doubled? I could find a solution to drop all subsequent postnotes that appeared immediately before.

Comment: yes now you understand what I mean... but it can't just recognize all as pages, because: (author, p. chapter 6) :D and I would prefer to find a solution where I can tell biblatex where to to drop postnote, because it could lead to problems, perhaps?

Comment: Though, drop all equal subsequent postnotes would be also very good, if you know how, I would be thankful, if you'd post it as answer :)

Comment: Well, this solution would not make everything into a page number, but would let all postnotes "qualify" for the tracker that checks if the previous note was the same. This `\ibid` command you seem to have in mind would probably have to manipulate quite some intestines of `biblatex`, I'll see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution comes pretty close to what you seem to want, the difference being that your proposed `\ibid` does exactly the opposite of my `\noibidonly`.

We modify `biblatex`'s trackers in such a way that all postnotes are considered for the "check-if-previous-postnote-was-the-same" tracker, not just proper page numbers.

```
\def\blx@loccit@stricttracker#1{%
  \global\csundef{blx@lastnote@#1@\abx@field@entrykey}%
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\blx@ifcitesingle
       {\global\cslet{blx@lastnote@#1@\abx@field@entrykey}\abx@field@postnote
           \xifinlistcs\abx@field@entrykey{blx@trackkeys@#1}
             {}
             {\listcsxadd{blx@trackkeys@#1}\abx@field@entrykey}}
       {}}}

\def\blx@loccit@numcheck#1{%
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{postnote}
    {\@secondoftwo}
    {\blx@imc@iffieldequalcs{postnote}{blx@lastnote@#1@\abx@field@entrykey}}}
```

This is just the standard definition with the `\ifpages` check deleted.

We then define `\noibidonly` to allow us to reset the postnote tracker, in effect causing the current and the next postnote to appear regardless of whether it has been displayed immediately before or not.

```
\newrobustcmd*{\noibidonly}{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\blx@loccit@reset{foot}}
    {\blx@loccit@reset{text}}%
}
```

We want to be able to use this command in the postnote, so we issue

```
\DeclarePageCommands*{\noibidonly}
```

(Though, thinking about it that should not be necessary any more.)

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,ibidpage]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@loccit@stricttracker#1{%
  \global\csundef{blx@lastnote@#1@\abx@field@entrykey}%
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\blx@ifcitesingle
       {\global\cslet{blx@lastnote@#1@\abx@field@entrykey}\abx@field@postnote
           \xifinlistcs\abx@field@entrykey{blx@trackkeys@#1}
             {}
             {\listcsxadd{blx@trackkeys@#1}\abx@field@entrykey}}
       {}}}

\def\blx@loccit@numcheck#1{%
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{postnote}
    {\@secondoftwo}
    {\blx@imc@iffieldequalcs{postnote}{blx@lastnote@#1@\abx@field@entrykey}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\noibidonly}{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\blx@loccit@reset{foot}}
    {\blx@loccit@reset{text}}%
}
\makeatother
\DeclarePageCommands*{\noibidonly}

\begin{document}
\cite[20]{cicero} and \cite[20]{cicero} and \cite[20]{cicero}.

\cite[p.~20:16]{wilde} and \cite[p.~20:16]{wilde} and \cite[p.~20:16]{wilde}.

\cite[lorem]{cicero} and \cite[ipsum]{cicero} and \cite[ipsum]{cicero}.

\cite[lorem]{wilde} and \cite[lorem]{wilde} and \cite[lorem\noibidonly]{wilde} and \cite[lorem]{wilde} and \cite[lorem]{wilde}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it is even a better solution than the one I asked for! The \noibidonly is a very good idea, as the the times I don't want it to be considered will be near zero! Just tested, working as excepted!!!