# Getting ibid for numeric citations while comparing optional arguments/postnotes from biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

Follow-up of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328246/98645).

The question and answer explain how to add `ibit` to a numeric style in biblatex.

But that solution is indeed likely longer than citing the number twice, because it cites a sentence like this:

> They say, “LaTeX is powerful“[96, p. 3], but state on the same page “WordTEX may be better”[96, p. 3]. On then next page, they talk about “trains driving backwards”[96, p. 4].

With the “ibit patch” applied, it is shown as this:

> They say, “LaTeX is powerful“[96, p. 3], but state on the same page “WordTEX may be better”[ibid., p. 3]. On then next page, they talk about “trains driving backwards”[ibid., p. 4].

However, obviously this still makes the text longer. I however, want that it also compares the postnote there… (i.e. the `3` in `\cite[3]{wildenhain2018}`)

Basically **[this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223134/make-biblatex-bibtex-recognize-equal-subsequent-postnotes)** calls for the same, but they use a different citation style.
As such, `ibidpage` is used and likely modified there – while I need to use `ibidtracker=constrict` as explained in the first question.

So simply *combining* these solutions *does not work*.

In the end, I'd like a result like this:

> They say, “LaTeX is powerful“[96, p. 3], but state on the same page “WordTEX may be better”[ibid.]. On then next page, they talk about “trains driving backwards”[ibid., p. 4].

If possible easily, maybe **also explain** how I could *only* print `ibid` *if* such a “complete matching” entry is found so it basically *never increases* the size of the citation. In the example, this would lead to this:

> They say, “LaTeX is powerful“[96, p. 3], but state on the same page “WordTEX may be better”[ibid.]. On then next page, they talk about “trains driving backwards”[96., p. 4].

How can this be achieved?

Note it also should be able to compare arbitrary data in the postnote. (as biblatex does not automatically prepend non-only-numeric arguments there, so one has to use `\cite[p. 3~ff.]{wildenhain2018}` or similar sometimes)

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but use `\cite[3\psqq]{wildenhain2018}` instead of *`\cite[p. 3~ff.]{wildenhain2018}` and `biblatex` will treat your postnote as purely numeric.

Comment: Note that it would be easier to get started helping you if you could share a short example document that already has the "ibid." modification from the first post and that produces the sample citation. Of course we can piece these things together from the information in the question, but an MWE is still a nice nod to those reading your question that you appreciate their time and want to help them get started right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer to [Getting ibid for numeric citations from biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/328230/35864), the code there does not implement the `ibidpage` function, but it is possible to transplant the code for `ibidpage` from say `authortitle-ibid.cbx` to this solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{ibidpage}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=constrict}}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=false}}}

\newtoggle{cbx:loccit}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:comp}{%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \addtocounter{cbx@tempcntb}{1}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifbool{bbx:subentry}
          {\iffieldundef{entrysetcount}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:comp}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:inset}}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:comp}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:shand}}}

\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
  \ifloccit
    {\global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}}

\letbibmacro*{orig:postnote}{postnote}
\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iftoggle{cbx:loccit}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{orig:postnote}}}
\makeatother

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{ibidtracker=constrict, ibidpage=true}


\begin{document}
  \autocite[3]{sigfridsson}
  \autocite[3]{sigfridsson}
  \autocite[4]{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The main ingredient is the new `cbx:loccit` flag and the `\ifloccit` test. Basically `\ifloccit` is `\ifopcit`+`\if<same page as last cite>`, where `\ifopcit` tests if the present citation is the same work that was last cited by the same author. Together `\ifciteibid` and `\ifloccit` give the desired "ibid."+page tracking.

[image: [1, p. 3] [ibid.] [ibid., p. 4]]

---

It is also possible to show "ibid." only if the last page was exactly the same. This is done by integrating the `\ifloccit` test directly into the `\ifciteibid` test that checks whether or not to print "ibid.".

Note that strictly speaking this does of course not take actual citation length into account. It purely chooses to print (or not to print) "ibid." based on the previous citation and the postnote argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newtoggle{cbx:loccit}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:comp}{%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \addtocounter{cbx@tempcntb}{1}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\ifloccit\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifbool{bbx:subentry}
          {\iffieldundef{entrysetcount}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:comp}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:inset}}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:comp}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:shand}}}

\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}

\letbibmacro*{orig:postnote}{postnote}
\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iftoggle{cbx:loccit}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{orig:postnote}}}
\makeatother

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{ibidtracker=constrict, loccittracker=constrict}


\begin{document}
  \autocite[3]{sigfridsson}
  \autocite[3]{sigfridsson}
  \autocite[4]{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1, p. 3] [ibid.] [1, p. 4]]

---

Both of these solutions use the standard definition of the `loccit` tests that only compare page ranges in the postnote argument. But the solutions can be combined with [Make Biblatex (Bibtex) recognize equal subsequent postnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223134/35864) if you absolutely insist that non-page-range input needs to be compared as well.

Comment: So again thanks a lot. I just discovered "I.c." and I want to use it here too. As such I've asked another follow-up question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/558160/98645